# ArrayList.toString Exception

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, classcastexception

I am using a ArrayList to store some Strings form an array of strings:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(strings[i]);
```

To give those to another function I converted them back into an Array:

```
foo((String[]) list.toArray());
```

this gives me an exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method call `list.toArray()` returns an array of type Object[]. You can't cast that to String[], even though it contains only Strings.

But you can create an array of type String[] with a sibling of List.toArray() that accepts an initial array of the desired type:

```
 foo( list.toArray( new String[ list.size() ] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
String[] t = new String[list.size()];
foo(list.toArray(t));
```